# Merge two binary search trees

Tags: binary-search-trees

Consider two binary search trees T1 and T2, each with height h, with all values in T1 less than all values in T2. I want to merge these both trees to get a new binary search tree of height at most h+1

**My Thoughts:**
The first thought was to put T1 as the left child of the leftmost node in T2. But the resulting bst will have height > h+1 I am not sure if there is a clever way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the smallest element from $T_2$ (it will be the left-most leaf) and call it $r$. Note that you may have to "fix" $r$'s right child by putting it in place of where $r$ was.

Make the new tree such that $r$ is the root, $T_1$ is the left-child of $r$ and $T_2$ (with $r$ removed) is the right-child of $r$

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. What if we wanted to merge two red-black trees? Will similar approach work?

Comment: Not as-is, because if $r$ is black, its parent is red and also it has a red right child - you can't just simply remove $r$ since it would create a red child of a red node.

Answer (score 1):

Either the rightmost node of the left tree or the leftmost node of the right tree can be used as a common root.